# Gulp adds suffix to import

Tags: angular, gulp, cropperjs

I'm trying to import cropperjs in my component.

```
import Cropper from 'cropperjs'
```

In my gulp-bundle.js there is method:

```
function moduleBundle() {
  return Promise.all([
    new Builder(builderConfig).bundle(`${build.paths.projectHome}/**/*`, `${build.paths.outputBundleDir}/${build.paths.projectHome}.js`, bundleConfiguration(false)),
  ]);
}
```

I'm not so familiar with gulp, but it adds .js suffix to my import and error says:

```
Error on fetch for cropperjs at file:///D:/user/front/app-module/cropperjs.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\user\front\app-module\cropperjs.js'
```

**EDIT:**

This is method that adds .js suffix:

```
function prepareSourceFiles() {
  return gulp.src([`${build.paths.outputBuildDir}/**/*.js`]).pipe(gulp.dest(build.paths.projectHome))
}
```